# SQL Query for reservation dates that break a month end?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I'm using a custom PHP function to produce a visual calendar for a **single month** that blocks out dates based on a table that contains an start date, and an duration - For example:

[image: Calendar Example]

...This is produced by data saying that the table should be blocked out for 4 days from the 14th, and 7 days from the 27th.

The query looks something like this:

```
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(start_date,'%d'),':', event_duration) AS info
    FROM events
   WHERE YEAR(start_date = '2012'
     AND MONTH(start_date) = '07'
ORDER BY start_date
```

(You could safely ignore the group concat and return the data as individual rows, that doesn't really matter).

I'm looking for a modification to the query that would block out dates at the start of the month IF an event starts in the previous month, but its length takes it into the following.

For instance - in the above example, the event on the 27th is actually scheduled to last 7 days in the database, so if I ran the query for `MONTH(start_date) = '08'` I'd like to say the first two dates blocked out, which they wouldn't currently be, because the start date that would block it out is not in the month being selected.

I'm fairly sure there's a subquery or something in there to grab the rows, but I just can't think of it.  Any takers?

***EDIT***

The answer from Salman below pointed me in the directon I wanted to go, and I came up with this as a way of getting carryovers from the previous month to show as '1st' of the month with the number of remaining days:

```
SELECT IF(MONTH(start_date) < '08', '2012-08-01', start_date) AS starter, 
       IF(MONTH(start_date) < '08', duration - DATEDIFF('2012-08-01',start_date), duration) AS duration
FROM EVENTS
WHERE YEAR(start_date) = '2012'
AND (MONTH(start_date) = '08' OR MONTH(start_date + INTERVAL duration DAY) = '08')
```

Obviously a lot of variables there to replace in PHP, so maybe there's an even better way?

Comment: Further info - I don't want to select the actual start date from a previous month (since the function just works on a day number).  So in the case of a 7 day event on the 27th of july, the query for AUGUST should return a date of 1st August, and a duration of 2 (for the 2 days in august that the 7 day event takes up).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Original Answer**:

Assuming that the month in question is `2012-07`, you need this query:

```
  SELECT column1, column2, columnN
   FROM `events`
  WHERE `start_date` <= '2012-07-01' 
    AND `start_date` + INTERVAL `duration` DAY > '2012-07-01'
ORDER BY start_date
```

**Revised Answer**:

Apparently you need a query that checks for overlapping (or conflicting) dates. The example dates are `2012-07-01` through `2012-08-01` and the query is:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM events
   WHERE '2012-08-01' > start_date
     AND start_date + INTERVAL duration DAY > '2012-07-01'
ORDER BY start_date
```

To constrain the start date and interval, you can use `SELECT ... CASE` statement:

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN start_date < '2012-07-01' THEN '2012-07-01' 
    ELSE start_date
END AS start_date_copy,
CASE 
    WHEN start_date < '2012-07-01' THEN duration - DATEDIFF('2012-07-01', start_date)
    ELSE duration 
END AS duration_copy,
FROM ...
```

Comment: To clarify, event length is always going to be set - if its a single day event, it will just be set to 1.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. In that case the `BETWEEN` query will screw things up. See revised answer.

Comment: I wanted to get the new month to show as being the first of the month, with remaining days.  You inspired me to a solution (edited into the question) but it seems as though there might be a better way to handle it?

Comment: I haven't actually tried running it, but your revised version looks like it will do the job and is cleaner than mine.  It probably runs faster too so I'll show your answer as the preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I was looking for, thanks to the other contributor for pointing me in the right direction and enabling me to solve it!

This is based on $yyyy and $mm coming from PHP (in my case, into a function call), and selecting individual rows rather than grouping:

```
SELECT start_date, duration
FROM reservations
WHERE YEAR(start_date) = '".$yyyy."'
AND  MONTH(start_date) = '".$mm."'

UNION

SELECT '".$yyyy."-".$mm."-01',
duration - DATEDIFF('".$yyyy."-".$mm."-01',start_date)
FROM reservations
WHERE YEAR(start_date) = '".$yyyy."'
AND MONTH(start_date) < '".$mm."'
AND MONTH(start_date + INTERVAL duration DAY) = '".$mm."'

ORDER BY start_date
```